# Bokeh CustomJS callback is not working for ColumnDataSource and RadioButtonGroup

Tags: python, bokeh

```
output_notebook()

STATS = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
sources, initial = [], 0
platforms = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

counts1 = pd.Series({'a': 100, 'b': 105, 'c': 55, 'd': 67})
cds1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(platforms=platforms, counts=counts1))
sources.append(cds1)


counts2 = pd.Series({'a': 600, 'b': 15, 'c': -10, 'd': 167})
cds2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(platforms=platforms, counts=counts2))
sources.append(cds2)

counts3 = pd.Series({'a': -200, 'b': -15, 'c': -55, 'd': -167})
cds3 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(platforms=platforms, counts=counts3))
sources.append(cds3)

radio = RadioButtonGroup(labels=STATS, active=initial)
source = sources[initial]
# source = copy.deepcopy(sources[initial])


print(sources)
for i in range(len(sources)):
  print(sources[i].data)

plot = figure(x_range=platforms, plot_width=800, plot_height=250, toolbar_location=None)
plot.title.text = STATS[initial]
graph = plot.vbar(x='platforms', top='counts', width=0.5, source=source)

callback2 = CustomJS(args={'source1': source, 'cds1': cds1, 'cds2': cds2, 'cds3': cds3, 'plot': plot, 'STATS': STATS}, code='''
    var choice = cb_obj.active;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600, height=200');

    if (choice == 0) {
      source1.data = cds1.data;
    } else if (choice == 1) {
      source1.data = cds2.data;
    } else {
      source1.data = cds3.data;
    }

    plot.title.text = STATS[choice];

    myWindow.document.write(choice);
    myWindow.document.write(source1);
    myWindow.document.write(source1.data['counts']);
    
    myWindow.document.write("<br>");
    myWindow.document.write(cds1.data['counts']);
    myWindow.document.write("<br>");
    myWindow.document.write(cds2.data['counts']);
    myWindow.document.write("<br>");
    myWindow.document.write(cds3.data['counts']);

    myWindow.print();
    
    source1.change.emit();
''')

radio.js_on_change('active', callback2)

layout = column(radio, plot)

show(layout)
```

When you click on any of the radio button groups (say: 2nd or 3rd), the 1st one automatically gets updated. It looks like as if there is a local reference has been created, because of which when it gets updated from 2nd or 3rd radio button group selection, the 1st one's data gets updated too.

I don't want to get it updated...

It should behave as if when I click on the individual selections, the plot should get updated accordingly by fetching the corresponding data through the callback.
[Image for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlJG4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `source` to be `cds1` here:

```py
source = sources[initial] # this is cds1
```

Then in your `CustomJS` code, you update `source` in every single branch. Therefore, regardless of what button is pressed you update `cds1`. You need to make an actual new, separate CDS for the glyph and use that, in order to keep everything separate.